# Intellij Structural Search for param type and actual type

Tags: intellij-idea, structural-search

Imagine I want to search for all the methods with any number of parameters that accepts as one of them Collection but are called by passing a List. Example:

- void test1(Collection x)
- void test2(A a,Collection x)
- void test3(Collection x, B b)
- void test4(List x, B b)

and I have:

- test1(myList) # Matches
- test1(aCollection) # NO match
- test2(xxx, myList) # matches
- test3(myList, xxx) # matches
- test4(myList, xxx) # Does not match as I am looking for calls to methods that receive collection and we pass a List.

Is there a way of using Structural search for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the calls to the methods, not the methods itself, you can use the following search template:

```
$call$($a$, $argument$, $b$)
```

With the following variable constraints:

#### a, b

- Minimum count: 0
- Maximum count: unlimited

#### argument

- Text/RegExp for java expression type: List
- Text/RegExp for formal argument type of the method: Collection